# PHP replace characters in a string "one-by-one" in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

There is MySQL query with unknown number of parameters (dynamically built) of the following format:

```
SELECT * FROM actions WHERE user1 = ? AND user10 = ? AND user11 = ? AND time = :time
```

Since I am using PDO prepared statement, I can't mix named and positional parameters in one query. So I need to repalce all question marks with named parameters sequentialy. I have an `Array()` that holds these parameters:

```
$parameters = Array();
$parameters['time'] = 1234567;
```

Now I need to replace every question mark with a sequential named parameter, so the query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM actions WHERE user1 = :user0 AND user10 = :user1 AND user11 = :user2 AND time = :time
```

And `$parameters` would contain every named parameter in it. I need to find every " ? " in the query string and looping through the occurences, replace them with an incrementing string. In JavaScript I would use a regex to find `?` and pass them to a function, which would have a global incrementing variable to track the current named parameter number, but I have no idea how to do this in PHP.

P.S. Besides replacing them sequentially, I would also need to add parameters to array:

```
$parameters['user0'] = $user;
$parameters['user1'] = $user;
$parameters['user2'] = $user;
```

Comment: are there users indeed the same? why all that mess then? just have one placeholder for all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: possible duplicate of [building db query with a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368594/building-db-query-with-a-for-loop)

Comment: @davidstrachan I already have a query built, but it contains `?` and named parameters, which is 'illegal' format. I only need to change `?` to named parameters in a loop.

Comment: Your TITLE suggests you otherwise.

Comment: @davidstrachan the `?` needs to be replaced in a specific manner (questions states how), which is probably done using the loop. It does not state anywhere that I need to **build** the query with a loop. Anyways, two questions are completely different even if the title looks simmilar. You can apply this question to any situation, even without the query.

Comment: As they say "I would not start here to go there".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All I was looking for:

```
$count = 0;
preg_replace_callback(
    "/\\?/",
    function ($matches) {
        global $count;
        return ':user' . (++$count);
    },
    $query_string
);
```

Which would return exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something  **extremely** strange.

First of all, there is not a single reason to combine different placeholders. Just make it

```
AND time = ?
```

and then just execute.

Yet if you want named parameters - add them at the same time you are building a query.
Apparently, `user1 = ? AND user10 = ? AND user11 = ?` being dynamically built. Why don't you just add named placeholders at the same time?

BTW, if you have to bind the same variable to all the marks, then just use the the single named placeholder for all

```
WHERE user1 = :user AND user10 = :user AND user11 = :user AND time = :time
```

then turn emulation mode off and then execute with

```
$stmt->execute(array('user'=>$user,'time'=>123));
```

Comment: I've tried `array('user'=>$user,'time'=>123)` before, but it did not work. What do you mean by emulation mode?

Comment: The query is built from arrays and if() statements, so it is hard to know how many question marks there will be and in which order they will appear.